# A \par[] version of \linebreak[]

Tags: line-breaking

I like how `\linebreak[]` takes an number 1-4 as how insistent you are about breaking. There are some long paragraphs in my paper, and I'd like to add option paragraphs in the middle of them. I know that `\linebreak[]` isn't appropriate because it doesn't end the line or indent the next line like `\par` or an empty line do.

Is there a command, package, or snippet that could accomplish this for me, sort of like this example, which does some awkward `\parskip`ing to avoid widowing the text shown at the beginning of page 82. Perhaps, if there were a paragraph break in the middle of the first paragraph, we could do away with the awkward `\parskip` glue.

[image: Page layout showing awkward parskip that might be avoided with an additional paragraph break]

> My own experiences with an adult literacy program provide an example of the types of situation that can arise if a language community has never developed an orthography statement, despite having quite a number of literacy materials, including a complete translation of the Bible. In preliminary research for the project, we noticed inconsistencies between texts, and linguistic analyses of the language had shown that there was a phonological feature that was not being represented. Unfortunately, we could not find an orthography statement that would address those issues.`\opar[2]` We started asking community members about spelling conventions, and a few people responded with the question, ``What did they do in the Bible?'' Essentially, they referred to the Bible translation as a sort of authority or standard for how the language could be written. However, a man who had worked on the Bible translation very humbly explained that the translation team had done their best to represent their language in the Bible, but that it probably had room for improvement. He believed that the conventions should not be considered final. Unfortunately, time was too short to hold community meetings to resolve the inconsistencies and evaluate whether the additional feature should be represented. The literacy program was being implemented by a faith-based agency, so it was important to them that the materials be consistent with the Bible. In the end, the writing team inferred the orthography rules from the text in the Bible.
>
> Using the Bible as a proxy for an orthography statement was pragmatic and expedient, but it leaves the power to define orthographic decisions that affect a million people in the hands of just a few Bible translators and educators. Publishing these materials using this untested system further solidifies a writing system that has not been widely discussed by the community, and that does not fully represent the language's phonology. The materials are currently being used in an informal education program. People are successfully learning to read, which is excellent, but every new set of materials produced using these conventions makes it more difficult to discuss whether changes might make the orthography easier to use.

If inserting a new paragraph break at `\par[<insistence>]` would help to reduce penalties, this hypothetical command would make a new paragraph. Otherwise, nothing happens.

Comment: Interesting concept, but really, there's not a place in this paragraph where starting a new paragraph wouldn't make a jarring, illogical break.  Maybe it would "look better" if one didn't actually read the content but that's not the purpose of a paragraph break.  TeX is very good at making a typeset paragraph look good, but it's quite incapable of understanding whether what it's setting has a deep meaning or is utter nonsense.  That's a matter for a philosopher.

Comment: If you would read my paper, @barbarabeeton, you'd know that there isn't any logic to lose!

Comment: Hopefully, this improved, real world example is what @barbarabeeton is looking for.

Comment: Yes, the example makes more sense, especially since I made the rash assumption on first reading that you wanted the potential break to be able to happen automatically at the end of every sentence.  But you are actually choosing the (relatively infrequent) possibilities, and that *does* make sense.  (As for writing papers that make no sense, I've done that and can sympathize.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this, although the sample text makes it a challenge to demonstrate -- the actual usefulness comes from technical writing and program documentation. I see no means to insert real paragraph breaks based on the line badness, but it can be faked. The core of a solution will look like `\filbreak` by having <*flexible skip*><*penalty*><*negative flexible skip*>. Getting the paragraph indent is a bit of a challenge.

One can't redefine `\par` without breaking a bunch of things, so define `\opar` (optional par).

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\opar[1][0]{%
  \ifvmode\else
    \@tempskipa\lastskip \unskip
    \nobreak
    \hfil
    %\hskip 2em minus 2em\relax
    \penalty \@getpen{#1}% allow break here
    \hfilneg
    %\hskip -2em minus -2em\relax
    \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ \hskip\@tempskipa \else \space \fi
    \hskip-\parindent
    \indent % discarding after break ends here
    \nobreak\hskip\z@skip % allow hyphenation of next word
    \ignorespaces 
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has
roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000
years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in
Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
literature, discovered the undoubtable source.\opar[1] Lorem Ipsum comes from sections
1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of ``de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum'' (The Extremes of Good
and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory
of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum,
``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\dots'', comes from a line in section 1.10.32.\opar[1]
The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for
those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from ``de Finibus Bonorum et
Malorum'' by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form,
accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

\end{document}
```

In the above test, there are two `\opar[1]`, with only the first one generating the fake `\par`.

There are a pair of lines commented-out in the definition. Un-comment them to discourage a full line of text above a fake `\par`.

Something that couldn't be handled is `\parskip` glue, so it is absent.

Besides `\parskip` there may be room for improvement regarding when to ignore or keep inter-word spaces. This (edited) version assumes an ordinary space follows when there is any space before. It always ignores the following space.

Comment: This is fantastic! It's a shame about not handling the `\parskip` glue. Could you help us understand why it can't incorporate it at a conceptual level?

Comment: Too much to go into. It has to do with the paragraph lines "setting" only at the end of the paragraph. This method uses the discarding of skips and penalties after a linebreak to have two sets of formatting, depending where the lines are eventually broken. If you *knew* at that point in the text that you wanted to insert `\par`, you could insert `\vspace{\parskip}`, but then you could give a real `\par`!

Comment: I interpreted the desire for `\par` so that an ordinary line break at that location is suppressed. To enable ordinary line breaks at that location, remove `\nobreak` from `\nobreak\hskip\z@skip`.